# Using two models in one FormWizard

Tags: python, django

I have two models set up in `models.py`: `Parent` and `Child`

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()


class Child(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    name = models.CharField()
```

Now, during form entry for these, I'd like to make a `FormWizard` where the first form takes in `Parent` and the second view takes in details of `Child` while keeping the details of the previous form. Is this possible? And if so, please guide me through some code samples.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible, and like you're suggesting the best thing for this is to use **Wizard Forms**. You can customize your wizard form using as many models as you want. I'll show you a sample way to create a form in 2 steps:

- First Step with a form to generate a **Parent** object
- Second Step to generate a **Child** object

I want to point that in this case maybe you could think about making a dynamic second step, just in case a Parent *can* have more than one Child. I ***strongly*** recommedn you to check both documentation pages:

- [Django Wizard Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/): This are useful to separate big forms or join different forms in one
- [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/) This are useful to have some kind of "dynamic" forms

---

**First Step: Create as many forms as you need for the wizard form (forms.py)**

- This forms you're going to create can be normal forms or ModelForms
- Change "NameForm01" for the name you want for the form

  `class NameForm01 (forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = Parent
          fields = ['name', 'city']`

  `class NameForm02 (forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = Child
          # We don't add the parent field because we relate the child
          # with the parent in the view
          fields = ['name' ]`

**Second Step: Create the Wizard view (views.py)**

```
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

class YourNameWizard(SessionWizardView):
    instance = None
    form_list = [NameForm01, NameForm02]
    template_name = "your_wizard_base.html"  # Template used to render the forms

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        # Parent Information is in form 0
        parent_name = form_list[0].cleaned_data['name']
        parent_city = form_list[0].cleaned_data['city']

        # Now we create the Parent object to relate with child
        new_parent = Parent(name=parent_name, city=parent_city)
        new_parent.save()

        # Child information is in form 1
        child_name = form_list[1].cleaned_data['name']

        # Now we create the Child object related with new_parent
        new_child = Child(name=child_name, parent=new_parent)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('your_return_url'))
```

**Third Step: Create the url to manage wizard forms (urls.py)**

```
from YOUR_PROJECT.forms import NameForm01, NameForm02
from YOUR_PROJECT.views.content import YourNameWizard
# ... other imports you have in your urls.py ...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... other patterns ...

    url(r'^your/url/?$', YourNameWizard.as_view([NameForm01, NameForm02]), name='your_url_name'),

    # ... other patterns ...
)
```

**Fourth Step: Create the template the wizard form will use**

*This template is the example template that django offers in the documentation* ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/))

Following this example you should call this template "your_wizard_base.html" and place it  in the **Templates** folder

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}
{% endif %}
</table>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This example template may be enough for you to practice with the WizardForm and then adapt it to your desires.